# How to fetch 100 records at a time until all the records in oracle using Spring JPA?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I wanted to read 100 records from Oracle and do some operation with that data then I need to do the same operation until all the records fetched from the database.

Using technologies:
Spring Boot
Spring JPA 
Oracle

Comment: Just search for "pagination". Be aware that those operations are not atomic, i.e. some `create`s, `insert`s, `update`s and/or `delete`s could happen between each bulk fetch. You could lock the whole database during the process, but this would mean that no other database actions could be performed in the mean time.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming

Comment: thanks, but I'm looking for which shouldn't lock/interrupt other database operations.

Answer (score 0):

I have used pagination as below:

```
@Repository
public interface SomethingRepository extends PaginationAndSortingRepository<Something, Long> {
    @Query("Select s from  Something s "
            + "join s.somethingelse as se "
            + "where se.id = :somethingelseid ")
    Page<Something> findBySomethingElseId(@Param("somethingelseid") long somethingelseid,
                                                                        Pageable pageable);
```